# Spark from_avro 2nd argument is a constant string, any way to obtain schema string from some column of each record?

Tags: json, apache-spark, schema, avro

suppose we are developing an application that pulls Avro records from a source
stream (e.g. Kafka/Kinesis/etc), parses them into JSON, then further processes that
JSON with additional transformations. Further assume these records can have a
varying schema (which we can look up and fetch from a registry).

We would like to use Spark's built in from_avro function, But it is pretty clear that
Spark from_avro wants you to hard code a >Fixed< schema into your code. It doesn't seem
to allow the schema to  vary row by incoming row.

That sort of makes sense if you are parsing the Avro to Internal row format.. One would need
a consistent structure for the dataframe.  But what if we wanted something like
from_avro   which grabbed the bytes from some column in the row and also  grabbed the string
representation of the Avro schema from some other column in the row, and then parsed that Avro
into a JSON string.

Does such built-in method exist?  Or is such functionality available in a 3rd party library ?
Thanks !

Comment: result dataframe will have one column with datatype string and that contains json (escaped). Is this requirement ? If yes, I think this is possible.

Comment: Hi. Yes. desired result: one column dataframe of type string consisting of the json result of parsing the binary avro bytes (using the avro schema for the row in which those bytes occurred).   That would do it !    Any idea where to find such function? / thnx!